# Is there any way to find the source of table in vertica?

Tags: database, pycharm, vertica

We've got vertica server, many data sources (hadoop hive, postgres, some inner airflow dag pipelines), from which data come. There are several tables, which data sources are unknown. Responsible people have disappeared, no info in colfuence, jira, etc. Tables have fresh data, regularaly refreshing. Is there any way to trace process, some data to find linked server?

Actually dont know where to start. I am using pycharm to work with vertica.

Comment: You can start by checking entries in `v_monitor.load_streams`. Also, you can check data in `v_monitor.user_sessions` to see who logged in from where. And you can `join` the table user_sessions with `v_monitor.query_requests` on `session_id, request_id` to see what query they executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try a query against both the `query_requests` and `load_streams` system tables:

If your table is `poc.tgt` and you suspect it's filled with an INSERT, go:

```
SELECT 
  session_id
, user
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(request, 'INSERT\s+INTO\s+poc.tgt', 1, 1, 'i') AS reqstart
FROM query_requests
WHERE regexp_ilike(request, 'INSERT\s+INTO\spoc.tgt')
LIMIT 64; -- the first 64 found should give you enough info
```

if your table's name is `with_array` and you suspect it's populated by a `COPY`, go:

```
SELECT 
  session_id
, user
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(request, 'COPY\swith_array') AS reqstart
FROM query_requests
WHERE regexp_ilike(request, 'COPY\swith_array')
LIMIT 64
```

Look at the other columns in `query_requests` and `load_streams` to see if you want to add other columns to your report - to find the populating process.

Also - join the `user_sessions` table with `query_requests` using `session_id` - and see if columns from `user_sessions` shed some more light on the matter.